# Sonar issue in case of nested Case statements

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using **Sonar(4.5.4**) for testing code quality. For this sample code:

```
switch (operationType) {

    case A:
        return doSomething1();

    case B:
        return doSomething2();

    case C:
        return doSomething3();

    case D:
        return doSomething4();

    case E:
        switch (X) {
            case X1:
                return doSomething5();
            case X2:
                return doSomething6();
            default:
                return doSomething7();
        }
    default:
        return doSomething8();

}
```

I got this as **critical** issue:

> End this switch case with an unconditional break, continue, return or throw statement.

for case **E** & **X1**. I have a return statement for every case (*Also, I included default*).

what is the reason for this problem?

Comment: Your code is fine. This case is probably just another in the list of code patterns that sonar doesn't understand. My favourite is its inability to detect coverage of lines/branches of a try-with-resources: Sonar thinks there are 8 branches in the catch, which you can never cover.

Comment: Please have a look in to below link,it might help you
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-415
http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/RE-Sonar-3-7-1-Java-Ecosystem-1-3-to-1-4-Complement-td5017817.html

Comment: @Bohemian Please note that this has nothing to do with SonarQube but this is an issue with JaCoCo, see : https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/82 and https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue (and so a bug in the analyzer) : 
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1336

The main problem behind your issue is that the check do not rely on analyzing the control flow of switch to raise an issue but rather purely on syntax which might end up in false negative (like in the ticket) or false positives (your case).